# Laravel / Eloquent : request that returns a count of id instances inside a table then stores it into a variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm currently working on a project on laravel 8.
I have 3 tables : 1.customers 2.books 3.loans
I want to be able to make a request like `$data=DB::table('emprunts')->where('customerid',$id->number)->first();` but where it would count the instances of loans with this customerid and return it into a variable.

I tried with

`$limitemprunts = Emprunt::WhereIn('clientid',$search_text)->where('clientid',$search_text)->distinct()->get()->count();`

but it gives me this error :

> TypeError Argument 1 passed to
> Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type
> array, string given, called in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\120\120\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php
> on line 919

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you're supplying a string instead of an array. I suspect that the source is `WhereIn`, which expects multiple entries. Turn your string into an array and feed it as such.

Comment: Also, it doesn't really make any sense to call both `WhereIn` and `where` in the same query, on the same column, with the same value. It's either one or the other, it can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to convert the second parameter of `whereIn` into an array:

```
$limitemprunts = Emprunt::WhereIn('clientid',[$search_text])->distinct()->get()->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, the answer was really simple : feed it an array